# How can I add a file to my .NET project at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a file at run time, and I want to add this file to my C# .NET project, also at run time. How can I do this?

Comment: you do not have any reference in your application to the .csproj-file which caused your build... so hardcoding is your only chance - use xml tools for this!

Comment: When you say "at run time" - can you clarify what you mean? Are you writing an IDE plugin? Because other than that **there is** no project at runtime. Heck, there doesn't need to be one at compile-time.

Comment: Also - what is the file? C#? an image? what?

Comment: I guess: You are working on a C# project, it can be compiled and run as .exe (or something else), when it's running there is some GUIs that allow users to add files to the project(the source of the running .exe)?

Comment: Or do you want to compile and load a C# file at runtime?

Comment: run time as in when i am executing my code. i want to create a file that i have created and want to add it to my current running project which is still under execution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a file to your .NET Project at runtime, as the project has been compiled, and your running application is not connected to your Project in any way.

If you're trying to load the contents of a file, it depends on the format of the file, but the simplest way would probably be using one of the following methods:

- [File.ReadAllText(string filename)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)
- [File.ReadAllBytes(string filename)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx)
- [File.ReadAllLines(string filename)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)